# How can i SUM records from a table to another after multiplying two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called orderItems which has two columns, quantity and unit price.It also has a foreign key `ordernumber` in that very table.

I have another table called ordergroup with primary key `ordernumber`, which contains SavedTotal column which is the order total based on quantity * unit price for all order item rows that reference that `ordernumber`.

Now what i struggle with is the sql query that can get all order items based on a certain ordernumber and calculate the total cost.

I have managed to do the multiplication but i am missing the SUM, here is my sql query(based on SQL Server) so far.

```
UPDATE OrderGroupNew
set OrderGroupNew.SavedTotal = OrderItemNew.UnitPrice*OrderItemNew.QUANTITY
    FROM OrderItemNew
    inner join OrderGroupNew on OrderItemNew.OrderNumber=OrderGroupNew.OrderNumber
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE OrderGroupNew
SET SavedTotal = (
    SELECT SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity)
    FROM OrderItemNew
    WHERE OrderNumber = OrderGroupNew.OrderNumber
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TVP as well :

```
;With o as (
        select OrderItemNew.OrderNumber as OrderNumber, 
        SUM(OrderItemNew.UnitPrice*OrderItemNew.QUANTITY) as OrderSum
        Group by OrderItemNew.OrderNumber)
UPDATE OrderGroupNew
set OrderGroupNew.SavedTotal = o.OrderSum
FROM o
INNER JOIN OrderGroupNew on o.OrderNumber=OrderGroupNew.OrderNumber
```

Well the 1st answer is correct too. Choose the best in term of performance :) (dont know which will be the best, to be honest ! )

Comment: since my application is for a demo, i do not really care about performance and the other one worked so :) thanks for taking the time to write this as well! might help other people in the future!